# How to animate deleting a paragraph letter by letter in React

Tags: string, reactjs, animation

I want to animate deleting part of an HTML paragraph letter by letter, as if holding down the delete key. It might be important to say that the text spans over multiple lines.

```
<p className="paragraph1">
  <span className="keep">Text that should not be deleted.</span>
  <span className="hide">Text that should be deleted.</span>
  <span className="keep">More text that should not be deleted.</span>
</p>

<p className="paragraph2">
  <span className="keep">Text that should not be deleted.</span>
  <span className="keep">More text that should not be deleted.</span>
  <span className="hide">Text that should be deleted.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to work with [this code](https://codepen.io/haaswill/pen/VKzXvZ), but I feel like the document.getElementBy method is not the best direction, for multiple reasons.

Comment: The code you have works pretty well, though it isn't using React. You're right that accessing the `document` manually would be the wrong way to do it using React. Are you asking for a React tutorial?

Comment: I am not asking for a React tutorial. How would you solve the document.getElementBy issue, without adding a ref to every single span?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you shouldn't access the DOM to show or modify the text.

```
const words = ["CSS3.", "HTML5.", "javascript."];
```

Strings should come from props for a more functional approach, or be stored in the component's state. Then you can simply use the timeout to modify the state.

And display the state inside the paragraphs of course.

Comment: I thought of that, but then the entire content of the page is going be store in the component's state. This is going to be a one-page website with a tl;dr function, that is going to shorten the entire text.

Comment: That's how React works. You use variables and a one-way data binding. Where is your text coming from? Is it the result of a fetch or is it just hard coded into the jsx? There's really no problem having all your text inside the state. But you could always use other ways to store (like redux), depends on your architecture.

Comment: It's a very simple site with hard coded text, so redux would be too much. I just thought there might be a better solution or a package. But thanks, I'll just do it like that then.